# Handling format errors in python

Tags: python, arrays, function, if-statement, format

Are there any ways of making a function that handles format-errors? Im not talking about regular int error I mean for example for this format: "%d/%m/%Y"?

Comment: I guess you are asking about string formatting? Google `python string formatting`, here an example: https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting . If you want to format dattime specifically, go for `python date format`. Otherwise, clarify your question. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way of handling errors in Python is to raise an exception, similar to how `int("foo")` raises a `ValueError`.  Given your example you could do:

```
def parse_date(date_string: str):
    """returns 3-tuple of ints, raising ValueError on invalid input"""
    try:
        nums = date_string.split("/")
        assert len(nums) == 3
        return int(nums[0]), int(nums[1]), int(nums[2])
    except AssertionError:
        raise ValueError("exactly three slash-separated ints expected")
```

Note that the `int()` conversion will raise its own `ValueError` if one of the individual `nums` is not an int, and the `except AssertionError` simply allows that to propagate up to the caller.

```
>>> parse_date("12/25/2020")
(12, 25, 2020)
>>> parse_date("lkjasdflkjasd")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in parse_date
AssertionError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in parse_date
ValueError: exactly three slash-separated ints expected
```

Now you can write code that calls this function and looks for a `ValueError` to tell it that the input value was wrong, like:

```
while True:
    try:
        day, month, year = parse_date(input("Enter date (%d/%m/%y): "))
        print(f"Remember remember the {day}th of {month}!")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Bad input: {e}")
```

```
Enter date (%d/%m/%y): sdlfkj
Bad input: exactly three slash-separated ints expected
Enter date (%d/%m/%y): 5/11/2020
Remember remember the 5th of 11!
```

Note that for the specific example of parsing a date, you probably want to use one of the `strptime` methods in the `datetime` module, which already does this work (and more) for you!

Comment: Thank you! But I did unfortunately get something wrong when I used the function: raise ValueError("exactly three slash-separated ints expected")
ValueError: exactly three slash-separated ints expected

Comment: That means that you passed in something that wasn't 3 slash-separated ints.  The error handling is working!